# Branded Email DocuSIgn

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

I have set up the branding options on dashboard/preferences.
The Sample email on dashboard looks as expected.
However when I send out the email for signing, triggered by an API call I get the default docusign email, and not the branded email that I have prepared.
Am I suppose to add something to the code to say use this brand for email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will want to include the BrandID in your envelope creation API call.

You can get the BrandID by editing your brand and then clicking on the Info tab.

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=brandid

Another option: Under branding preferences, you can specify which brand should be used as your 'sign default', so in the event that a brandID is not provided, this specific brand will be used.

Comment: I have only one, and it is set to default.